# Fourier Transform of delta(2n)

Tags: discrete-mathematics, fourier-transform

So if I have the function h[n] = delta[2n]
How can I find its Fourier Transform? How does FT behave in general when the input function is downsampled (i.e. x[n]->x[2n])?

I know that I can get the answer from MATLAB easily, but I want to understand the steps...thanks!!!

Comment: how do you define $\delta[2n]$ ? (in latex $\$\text{\delta[2n]}\$$)

Comment: I don't know. It's very confusing for me because δ[2n] is still only 1 when n=0

Comment: latex... so its discrete time Fourier transform is the same as $\delta[n]$